# Systemd not able to switch off Wacom touch on resume

Tags: 16.04, suspend, systemd, wacom

I have a Wacom Bamboo tablet which has a touchpad function I almost never use—it mostly gets in the way. I have a script which switches that function off, run via a .desktop file in `~/.config/autostart`. This works fine and I have no problem running the script from a terminal either.

The problem is that after resuming from suspend, the touch function reactivates. Prior to upgrading to 16.04, this script was called from `/etc/pm/sleep.d/wacom` which switched it off again. After upgrading I’ve tried doing the same thing using systemd (`/lib/systemd/system-sleep/wacom`), but there seems to be something very different about the context in which it’s run because the command produces puzzling errors.

Syslog shows `wacom_set_report: ran out of retries (last error = -32)` and error -32 seems to mean “communication pipe broken”.

Logging output shows that even getting the status fails—`xsetwacom get "$DEVICE" touch`* returns no output when it should report “on” or “off”. Running the command to switch off touch (`xsetwacom set "$DEVICE" touch off`) returns “`Failed to open Display .`”.

I also get this—`warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh` but the script runs fine for me using `sh`.

I’ve tried adding a `sleep` command before calling the script but it doesn’t seem to help. I’ve called it using `at` (`at now + 1 min -f`), but the result is the same—even though it’s running well after resume the script still can’t even get the device status. I tried putting the status command into a while loop, but it never broke out of the loop (no status was returned), yet at the same time I could run the command successfully in a terminal.

I’ve also tried putting the command directly in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/wacom`.

This is fairly trivial, but annoying that this used to work, but now doesn’t.

·

*`DEVICE="Wacom Bamboo 2FG 6x8 Finger touch"` as returned by `xsetwacom list dev`.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not really.  I’ve got used to unplugging it more and I’ve also moved to Manjaro (+Cinnamon).  I have an indicator in the panel (using Bash Sensors indicator) which shows whether touch is active & runs my script to toggle touch input when I click on it.  I think I had a similar thing setup under Gnome (Ubuntu) with another indicator extension.

Comment: I've had a problem which seems similar and have resolved it: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=367475